# editing SVN Access control file

Tags: linux, unix

I opened a svn Access Control file to change permissions for few users and I accidentally ended up adding so many newlines in the file. I am new to linux commands and I dont know how I can remove these newlines from the file.
I am using below command to open access file in editing mode:
vi /etc/svn-access-control

Here is the screenshot of newlines added in file.
[image]

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post such questions on [Unix/Linux stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

To join a line use

```
:j
```

Or

```
J
```

From [here](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~cslab/vi.html)